# cubic function root bisection search time limit exceeded

Tags: c++, numeric, bisection

I have implemented this solution for finding a root of a cubic function

`f(x) = ax3 + bx2 + cx + d`

given `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, ensuring it's being monotonic.

After submitting the solution to an online judge without being shown the test cases, I am being faced by a time limit error. `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` guarantee that the function is monotonic and we know it is being continuous. The code first finds the interval `[A, B]` such that `f(A) * f(B) < 0`; then the code moves to implement the bisection search.

What I want to know is if there is some possibility to minimize the time complexity of my code so it passes the online judge. The input is `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and the output should be the root with an error `0.000001`.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <string>

using namespace std;

int f(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x) {
    return x*(x*(a*x + b) + c) + d;
}

int main() {

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    double a, b, c, d, A, B, x = 1, res;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d; 

    //determinning the interval
    double f_x = f(a, b, c, d, x);
    if (a > 0) { // strictly increasing
        if (f_x > 0) { B = 0;
            while (f(a, b, c, d, x) >= 0) { x -= x; }
            A = x; }
        else { A = 0;
            while (f(a, b, c, d, x) <= 0) { x += x; }
            B = x; }
    }

    else { //strictly decreasing
        if (f_x > 0) { A = 0;
            while (f(a, b, c, d, x) >= 0) { x += x; }
            B = x; }
        else { B = 0;
            while (f(a, b, c, d, x) <= 0) { x -= x; }
            A = x; }    
    }
    // Bisection Search
    double l = A;
    while ((B - A) >= 0.000001)
    {
        // Find middle point 
        l = (A + B) / 2;

        // Check if middle point is root 
        if (f(a, b, c, d, l) == 0.0)
            break;

        // Decide the side to repeat the steps 
        else if (f(a, b, c, d, l)*f(a, b, c, d, A) < 0)
            B = l;
        else
            A = l;
    }
    res = l;
    cout.precision(6);
    cout << fixed << " " << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (f(a, b, c, d, l) == 0.0)` -- Checking for exactly 0.0 is not a good idea.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: i saw the code already earlier today. `x -= x;` is still wrong ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 It has been corrected, please tell me where, it prints correct results now, you can check if you have a b c d to make the function monotonic.

Comment: `x -= x;` is the same as `x = 0;` and if that wont make you leave the while loop you never will leave it

Comment: x = 1 there now not 0

Comment: `x -= x;` is exactly the same as `x = x - x;` which is... `x = 0;`

Comment: formerlyknownas_463035818 is telling you. Change to `x = -x`.

Comment: when writing an iteration with maths involved I would always implement a maximum loop count. Any mistake you make can make the iteration not converge. This can be caught easily if you limit the number of iterations

Comment: @Ripi2 no I am not! I am just saying that `x = 0;` cannot be correct

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Strictly speaking, yes, you told what you told. But you also pointed to the bug.

Comment: @Ripi2 `x = -x;` would iterate forever as well. I really dont know what OP wanted to actually choose as next step

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The problem with these online judges is that we don't know the input. For test, I suggest to take a never null 2nd order polynomial and to integrate it to get a monotonic one

Comment: @Damien the problem is not really the online judges tests, but the absense of any other known reproducible tests, just saying ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to determine the initial interval, just take `[-DBL_MAX, +DBL_MAX]`. The tolerance can be chosen to be 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

The following code implements these ideas:

```
// This function will be available in C++20 as std::midpoint
double midpoint(double x, double y) {
    if (std::isnormal(x) && std::isnormal(y))
        return x / 2 + y / 2;
    else
        return (x + y) / 2;
}

int main() {
    ...
    const auto fn = [=](double x) { return x * (x * (x * a + b) + c) + d; };

    auto left  = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    auto right =  std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

    while (true) {
        const auto mid = midpoint(left, right);
        if (mid <= left || mid >= right)
            break;

        if (std::signbit(fn(left)) == std::signbit(fn(mid)))
            left = mid;
        else
            right = mid;
    }

    const double answer = left;
    ...
}
```

Initially, `fn(x)` can overflow and return `inf`. No special handling of this case is needed.

Comment: hard to beat, any better start interval will just save only a couple of iterations

Comment: Very impressive. A little room for speed  improvment: here function is called twice per iteration. Could be handled easily if needed